# SQL: Keep a single row based on other column values within a group

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Say we have this table:

```
user_id order       product
1       1           a
1       2           b
1       3           b
2       1           a
2       2           c
3       1           c
3       2           a
3       3           a
```

Out of this table, my aim is to create a new one which would be meant to keep a single row for each unique `user_id` whereas `product` ideally should display the one corresponding to the last order placed by each user. In other words, the expected output would look as follows:

```
user_id   last_product
1         b
2         c
3         a
```

Until now I've been unsuccessfully trying back and forth via `CASE WHEN` statements, i.e. using queries like that one below:

```
SELECT user_id
     , CASE WHEN order = MAX(order) THEN product END AS last_product
FROM table
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

Ideally I would like to achieve this without having to use any sort of CTE. Is there any simple and graceful solution to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use window function `row_number()` to assign a unique sequential number to each row of a partition, then select only the first ones, the order `desc` will assign 1 to the last order placed by each user.

```
select user_id, product as last_product
from (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by user_id order by ordr desc) as rn
  from mytable
) as s
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an excellent use case for Qualify

```sql
select user_id, product as last_product
from t0
qualify row_number() over (
    partition by user_id
    order by order_no desc
) = 1;
```

| USER_ID | LAST_PRODUCT |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | b |
| 2 | c |
| 3 | a |

Answer (score 0):

I think `last_value()` will read more self-explanatory

```
select distinct 
       user_id,
       last_value(product) over (partition by user_id order by ordr) as last_product
from my_table;
```

One thing to keep in mind is Snowflake's note on their implementation of [`last_value()`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/last_value)

> If no window_frame is specified, the default is the entire window:
>
> ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
>
> This differs from the ANSI standard, which specifies the following
> default for window frames:
>
> RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW

You can also use the order column to qualify rows like you were attempting to do in your question. BTW `order` is a reserved keyword so I suggest using a different column name to prevent unexpected errors in the future.

```
select user_id,
       product as last_product
from my_table
qualify order = max(order) over (partition by user_id);
```